# $\gamma=0$? Where is my error?

Tags: limits

First of all, the Taylor expansion for $\ln(1+x)$ is

$$\ln(1+x)=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{k+1} x^k}{k}$$

It follows that

$$\lim_{x\to-1}\left(\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{k+1} x^k}{k}-\ln(1+x)\right)=0$$

consequently,

$$\lim_{t\to1}\left(\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{ t^k}{k}-\ln (1-t)\right)=0$$

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\left(\sum _{k=1}^{t } \frac{ 1}{k}+\ln t\right)=0$$

On the other hand, we have

$$\lim _{{t\rightarrow \infty }}\left(\sum _{{k=1}}^{t}{\frac {1}{k}}-\ln t\right)=\gamma$$

So where is the error?

Comment: The error is the "It follows" statement.

Comment: How do you know that the limit is $0$?  Be cautious about where the sum converges.

Comment: How does the first consequently statement imply the second?

Comment: Also note that $$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{ t^k}{k}=-\ln (1-t)$$ so $$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{ t^k}{k}-\ln (1-t)=-2\ln (1-t)$$ and it is clearly incorrect to have $$\lim_{t \to 1}-2\ln (1-t)=0$$ Might also be worth pointing out that the limit you are taking does not exist from the left

Comment: Interchanging limits (sums, integrals, limits, etc.) always needs justification.

Comment: You taking an analytic function, $f(x)=\log(1+x)$, and assuming that its power series in $x=0$ converges to $f(x)$ for $x=-1$, having an absolute value that equals the radius of convergence. That cannot hold, since $\log(1+x)$ has a wild singularity in $x=-1$.